# ASP.NET Membership user forgot password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

Q: Is there a mechanism per mvc3/asp.net membership provide/object where if a user forgets his/her username is there a way to reset it or figure out what it is and programatically send it back to the user or a link that has them re-register?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Membership provider in your ASP.NET MVC project you can easily implement the password recovery views/controllers/models. I've got an example of this on my blog:

http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/Password-Recovery-in-an-ASP.NET-MVC-Project

Answer (score 2):

Check this site out. It is very in-depth and should get you on the right track. It is done programatically.

http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/recovering-and-changing-passwords-cs

If instead you want to do it with less code-behind, you'll end up using the `PasswordRecovery` control that is part of the membership system. You can find some details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178335(v=vs.80).aspx

If you have membership setup in a normal fashion, you can use the default control. Examples from the link above.

```
<asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" Runat="server">
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

You will probably need to grant anonymous access to the form that has this control. Do that in the web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="RecoverPassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="UserLogin.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you need any help getting to the right place, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.resetpassword.aspx